# Jquery ajax call on IOS return status 400

Tags: android, jquery, ios, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to submit form with files with the following call :

```
 var formData = new FormData(this);
 $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/action",
    success: function (msg) {
       console.log(msg);

    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

it works fine in web browser including safari
it works fine in android OS

but in IOS the call failed and return error 400

[image]

Comment: Do you have `AllowsArbitraryLoads` set as `YES` in info.plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $form = $(this); // <- change this depending on your scope/usecase

        $form.find('input[name][type!="file"], select[name], textarea[name]').each(function(i, e) {
            if ($(e).attr('type') == 'checkbox' || $(e).attr('type') == 'radio') {
                if ($(e).is(':checked')) {
                    formData.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e).val());
                }
            } else {
                formData.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e).val());
            }
        });
        // [type="file"] will be handled separately
        $form.find('input[name][type="file"]').each(function(i, e) {
            if ($(e)[0].files.length > 0) {
                formData.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e)[0].files[0]);
            }
        });
```